# Python: Dynamically importing a script in another folder from a string

Tags: python

I need to import and run a script from a string (path) which is located in another folder. The input needs to be completely dynamic. The code below works when the file is in the same folder but I can't seem to get it working when the file is located elsewhere.

main.py

```
path = 'bin\TestScript'

module = __import__(path)

my_class = getattr(module, '__main__')

instance = my_class(3,16)

print(instance)
```

TestScript.py

```
def __main__(a,b):

    return(a*b)
```

Get the errror:
ImportError: No module named 'bin\\TestScript'

on windows os

Comment: So what is exactly the problem? Do you get an error?

Comment: Which os are you using?

Comment: Get the errror: ImportError: No module named 'bin\\TestScript'

Comment: `bin\TestScript` is not a *module name*. The correct name would be something like `bin.TestScript`. Module names != file paths.

Comment: What is the input like? Could you give an example of that input?

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate the directory from the module name and add that to the module search path.  For example:

```
import os.path
import sys

path = 'bin\\TestScript'
mdir = os.path.dirname(path)
modname = os.path.basename(path)
sys.path.append(mdir)

module = __import__(modname)

my_class = getattr(module, '__main__')

instance = my_class(3,16)

print(instance)
```

An alternative is to make the directory "bin" a package.